# Junits using Mocks scala traits and cake pattern

Tags: scala, mocking, cake-pattern

I have a scala trait as follows -

```
trait Mytrait {
   def saveData : Boolean = {
      //make database calls to store
      true
   }
    def getData : Integer = {
        //get data from database
        return i
    }

}
```

Now I have heard about cake pattern but I am not able to figure out how I can apply cake pattern for mocking traits like this.

Can anyone point out on how this can be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would do it something like this:

```
trait Mytrait { this: DbConnectionFactory => // Require this trait to be mixed with a DbConnectionFactory
  def saveData : Boolean = {
    val connection = getConnection // Supplied by DbConnectionFactory 'layer'
    //use DB connection to make database calls to store
    true
  }

  def getData : Integer = {
    val connection = getConnection // Supplied by DbConnectionFactory 'layer'
    val i: Integer = ... // use DB connection to get data from database
    return i
  }

}

trait DbConnection

trait DbConnectionFactory {
  def getConnection: DbConnection
}

// --- for prod:

class ProdDbConnection extends DbConnectionFactory {
  // Set up conn to prod Db - say, an Oracle DB instance
  def getConnection: DbConnection = ???
} // or interpose a connection pooling implementation over a set of these, or whatever

val myProdDbWorker = new ProdDbConnection with Mytrait

// --- for test:

class MockDbConnection extends DbConnectionFactory {
  // Set up mock conn
  def getConnection: DbConnection = ???
}

val myTestDbWorker = new MockDbConnection with Mytrait
```

where you form the 'layers' or your 'cake' from a suitable DbConnectionFactory and your trait.

This is just a simple example, you could expand on the number of components involved, have multiple implementations of MyTrait that you want to work with under different cirumstances, etc. See, for example [Dependency Injection in Scala: Extending the Cake Pattern](http://www.warski.org/blog/2010/12/di-in-scala-cake-pattern/)